# Oracle histograms not useful for nested sets

Tags: database, oracle, histogram, nested-sets, peoplesoft

We use PeopleSoft.   It uses joins against self referencing trees in order to implement row level query security.   This is accomplished using nested sets.   As you can picture, the leaf nodes return only one row, while further up the tree, it returns a long list.   This is skewed data with a large number of the rows being the one row returned.   Unfortunately, most of the items used from the tree are actually the large sets returned.   Since this is a nested set, it is always a range query, never an equal query.   Oracle's histograms, from what I read, are only applied to equality conditions.

This causes very inefficient query plans, using the "merge join Cartesian" plan for sets of thousands of rows.  The join to the tree is implemented as a delivered view, so all of the attempts I have made at cardinality hints have failed.

Is there a way that any of you know to help it to better estimate cardinality, so that it will make a reasonable query plan?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "delivered view"?

Comment: The only way I've ever found is to use the CARDINALITY hint. I guess you may not have that option.

Comment: Now I recall two other tricks: 1. Use materialize hint or WHERE ROWNUM>0 to force it to materialize a dataset and realize it has a given cardinality. 2. If you need it to know there is only one row, use a (redundant) aggregate function so that it always knows only record is returned.

Comment: Have you looked into "Dynamic Sampling"?